# Spring transactionManager is Rolling back, while testexception=[null]!

Tags: java, spring-transactions

Why is the transaction being rolled back while there is no `Exception`? The object is not being saved.
I have defined the transaction parameters like:

```
 @Transactional(value = "transactionManager", timeout = 30, rollbackFor =
 java.lang.Exception.class)`.
```

This is what logs say about the transaction.

```
org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener
endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction after test execution for test context [TestContext@51e2a069
testClass = DAOTest, testInstance = sample.library.dao.DAOTest@7591777e, testMethod =
testSaveDao@DAOTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration =
[MergedContextConfiguration@213c2d7f testClass = DAOTest, locations = 
'{classpath:/applicationcontext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]',
activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 
'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent =
[null]]]
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.634 sec
```

Here is the whole log of `DAOTest` class:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: sample.library.dao.DAOTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.634 sec
```

what's being done wrong? I can give more information if necessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `INFO` level should give a hint that this is not an error message. Your test rolls back by default, regardless of the primary setting on the service-level method. To avoid rollback (if you really want to) you need an annotation on the test class itself, as documented in the [Annotations section of the Testing chapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations) in Spring documentation. The annotation in question is `@Rollback`.