# testException = [null] with Hibernate and SpringMVC

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I've got the following test I'm trying to run. 
In this case just a blank test to try it out but for some reason it's not working.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class UserHibernateDaoTest {

    private static final long USERID = 1;
    private static final long NONEXISTENTUSERID = -1;
    private static final String FIRSTNAME = "TestFirstName";
    private static final String LASTNAME = "TestLastName";
    private static final String EMAIL = "test1@mail.com";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "TestPassword";
    private static final String PHONENUMBER = "0000000";
    private static final String ROLE = "USER";

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private UserHibernateDao userHibernateDao;  
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Before
    @Transactional
    public void setUp() {
            this.userHibernateDao = new UserHibernateDao();
            User u;
            u = new User();
            u.setUserid(123);
            u.setFirstName(FIRSTNAME);
            u.setLastName(LASTNAME);
            u.setEmail(EMAIL);
            u.setPassword(PASSWORD);
            u.setPhoneNumber(PHONENUMBER);
            u.setRole(ROLE);
            em.persist(u);

    }

    @Rollback
    @Test
    public void testCreate() {
            // Trying to run this empty test
    }
}
```

I get the following when I run it:

```
INFO: Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@16fb356 testClass = UserHibernateDaoTest, testInstance = ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence.UserHibernateDaoTest@6bc248ed, testMethod = testCreate@UserHibernateDaoTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@224b4d61 testClass = UserHibernateDaoTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence.TestConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@23a9ba52]; rollback [true]
Jan 15, 2020 1:17:10 PM org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext endTransaction
INFO: Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@16fb356 testClass = UserHibernateDaoTest, testInstance = ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence.UserHibernateDaoTest@6bc248ed, testMethod = testCreate@UserHibernateDaoTest, testException = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: ar.edu.itba.paw.models.User, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@224b4d61 testClass = UserHibernateDaoTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence.TestConfig}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
```

If change Rollback() to Rollback(false) I get:

```
 RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

In case you find it neccesary I published my TestConfig in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59754882/8518930)

Answer (score 0):

Spring do not find you User class as entity. So it does not know about User being an entity. You need to add entity package to component scan in `TestConfig` class.

```
@ComponentScan({"src.main.java.ar.edu.itba.paw.persistence", "ar.edu.itba.paw.models" })
```

Comment: I've been able to test inside my services section importing the User model and it works (instead of adding it to componentScan), so I was trying to do the same here. Anyways, I tried your solution and I still get the same exception.

Comment: in your configuration you are setting ```factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("src.main.java.ar.edu.itba.paw.models");``` it should start from `ar.edu.itba`

Comment: Unfortunately no, though I managed to get my test passed commenting a few more lines. I still get the testException though.

Comment: `@ComponentScan` is for beans. `@EntityScan` is for entities.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed can you post some code on github it should work.
@neildo I have my application where it is running without using `@EntityScan` may be I am using different version

Comment: @BilalShah you must have it configured in your persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your TestConfig class with `@EntityScan("ar.edu.itba.paw.models")`. Also make sure your entity class is annotated with `@Entity`

Comment: I'm using SpringMVC, I'm not sure this is the solution?

Comment: You are are using EntityManager which is JPA. This should work. Give it a try.